# find the subset sorted according to absolute difference between rows in specific columns in a matrix

Tags: r, sorting, matrix, subset, minimum

Please help me on the following code.

```
set.seed(5)
matrix <- matrix(round(rnorm(100,100,50)), nrow = 4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE,
             dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3","r4"),c("c1","c2")))
```

I need a subset/rows  of above matrix where the `absolute difference` of `row r1` and rest of the `rows` in `column c1` . If i could `sort` the rows by the `difference` in increasing order that also will be useful. From there i can find the rows with `minimum` difference values.

Input matrix

```
   c1   c2
r1 10  4
r2 6   11
r3 9   17
r4 21  91
```

Output Matrix

```
   c1   c2
r1 10   4
r2 9    17
r3 6    11
r4 21   91
```

`row r1` remain as reference. `row r2 to r3` sorted according to increasing difference from `row r1` in `column c1`.Any help/clues appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the absolute difference? ie which `j` minimises `sum(abs(matrix[1,3:4] - matrix[j,3:4]))` ?

Comment: @Spacedman May be could not raise my query properly. I want to find the `lowest abs difference between row r1 and other rows` in `column c3 first` and then `sorted according to increasing abs difference in column c4` . I think `min abs diff` in a single row in multiple columns may not be always possible. I hope i could clarify my query this time.

Comment: Maybe my answer I just posted is too much. Edit your Q to show your matrix and show and explain the result you want (which you can work out by hand for this example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can calculate the absolute differences between row 1 and all rows (concerning columns 3 and 4) with the following command:

```
differences <- abs(t(t(matrix[ , 3:4]) - matrix[1, 3:4])) 

#     c3 c4
# r1   0  0
# r2  39 36
# r3 124 44
# r4   9 11
# r5  75 17
```

Now you can order these differences by the first column (`c3`) in the first place and column 2 (`c4`) in the second place. This order is used to order your original `matrix`:

```
matrix[order(differences[ , 1], differences[ , 2]), ]

#     c1  c2  c3  c4
# r1  58 169  37 104
# r4  46  92  46  93
# r2 186  70  76  68
# r5  70  -9 112  87
# r3  86 107 161  60
```

---

**Update based on new example in question:**

```
differences <- abs(t(t(matrix[ , ]) - matrix[1, ])) 

#    c1 c2
# r1  0  0
# r2  4  7
# r3  1 13
# r4 11 87

matrix[order(differences[ , 1], differences[ , 2]), ]

#    c1 c2
# r1 10  4
# r3  9 17
# r2  6 11
# r4 21 91
```

Comment: You rock.I got the clue.:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `c3` and `c4` are columns 3 and 4, use apply to compute the sum of absolute differences between row 1 and the other rows. Within the function in  the `apply` call, `r` is a vector of each row:

```
> apply(matrix,1,function(r){sum(abs(r[3:4]-matrix[1,3:4]))})
 r1  r2  r3  r4  r5 
  0  75 168  20  92
```

The first one is zero, which is good because thats the sum of absolute difference of row 1 with itself. So proceed:

```
> diffs = apply(matrix,1,function(r){sum(abs(r[3:4]-matrix[1,3:4]))})
> diffs
 r1  r2  r3  r4  r5 
  0  75 168  20  92
```

To find the index of the smallest, ignoring the zero, take the first element off, find the first one which is minimum (this will only take one if there's ties...) and add one back:

```
> 1+which(diffs[-1]==min(diffs[-1]))[1]
r4 
 4
```

To reorder your matrix by increasing sum abs diff:

```
> order(diffs)
[1] 1 4 2 5 3
> matrix[order(diffs),]
    c1  c2  c3  c4
r1  58 169  37 104
r4  46  92  46  93
r2 186  70  76  68
r5  70  -9 112  87
r3  86 107 161  60
```